# Python pip3 install error Librosa M1 Silicon Chip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, librosa

I am trying to install the library librosa into my python3 environment. When I run

```
pip3 install librosa
```

I am greeted with this error,

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=/private/var/folders/nd/pcbm774s1mv18bkfzgvk2g480000gn/T/pip-install-78ukqo1x/scipy_2253c8d2f45740a7acf86c6f0c0a0e1f/.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8', '/private/var/folders/nd/pcbm774s1mv18bkfzgvk2g480000gn/T/pip-install-78ukqo1x/scipy_2253c8d2f45740a7acf86c6f0c0a0e1f', '/private/var/folders/nd/pcbm774s1mv18bkfzgvk2g480000gn/T/pip-install-78ukqo1x/scipy_2253c8d2f45740a7acf86c6f0c0a0e1f/.mesonpy-q01ptbei/build']'
```

The error is much longer, but I think this is the main piece of it. If more is needed please let me know.

I've tried different remedies, initially I thought SciPy was having an issue downloading onto my M1 chip which was printing this, so I went through steps and got SciPy installed properly, but this issue still persists - librosa is fairly niche, so not much support.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a solution, but if you become as desperate as me;

I hosted a virtual Windows 10 machine on Azure and downloaded PyCharm there. Make sure your Python isn't the newest - librosa only works with 3.7 >= and < 3.11 - after I got this windows machine running, correct Python version installed, Librosa finally installed and I was able to execute my Python file.

Edit: Didn't try downgrading my Python version on my Mac, but may be worth trying. I'm using Python 3.9 on my VM.